# Chain Multiple Elements In HTML2PDF?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, html2pdf

I have a page that looks like this: https://www.pdffiller.com/jsfiller-desk16/?isShareViaLink=1&requestHash=0b686d3412abda4ce3280790c21ed048547fe38efb37cfe5eedfc9ab11dc5674&lang=en&projectId=1109967956&loader=tips&MEDIUM_PDFJS=true#9d3d7d408e8045169526ca212483a79f

[Sorry for the long link]

Sadly, I cannot save the PDF so I am trying to print every page. Each page has a div element with a `[data-page-id="0"]` wjere id=0 is the page number, starting from 0.

I have a sample script here

```
async function testShot() {

 var element = document.querySelector(`div[data-page-id="0"]`);

    await html2pdf(element, {
      margin: 0,
      width: "1442px",
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 1,
        height: element.offsetHeight,
        width: element.offsetWidth,
      },
      height: "1866.12px",
      filename: "test.pdf",
      image: { type: "png", quality: 0.98 },
    });
}
```

And it works but how can I chain this for multiple elements into 1 pdf?